# Tiktok embed on gatsby project disappears on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Scenario:

- I have a gatsby site with a wordpress backend.
- Tiktok embeds don't render unless the embed script is included separately.  I used `react-script-tag` to include `https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js` and I can see the embedded tiktok video in the dev environment.
- I can also see the embed when I view a production build locally.
- I cannot see the embed on a deploy preview on Netlify.  It appears to partially render and then the content disappears.

Upon inspecting the Network tab in the developer tools, I noticed that tiktok calls `https://www.tiktok.com/embed/v2/<video-id>?lang=en-US`.

- On Netlify its content length is 0 whereas local it's not.
- Response header is way shorter than on local.
- On Netlify the `content-type` is `application/json` whereas on local it's `text/html`.
- On Netlify there is a `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json` warning in the console.

Here are some screenshots to compare:

Netlify
[image: screenshot of netlify response header]

Local
[image: screenshot of local response header].

I've tried adding the player via oembed, but the result is the same. I've also reached out to Netlify support if for whatever reason something on their end may have caused it, but no dice.

Why is there a discrepancy between local and Netlify and is there a way for me to fix it?

Comment: Hi @vandas. Have you seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767867/embed-video-from-tiktok

Comment: @ksav yes, I gave that a try after my initial attempt didn't work but I'm still having the same problem.